# remove unused parts of query string leaving untouched the restant parameters using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, query-string

In the past I had a php calendar that integrated into my php pages and produced two clickable links `Previous` and `Next` that were `month=xx` and `year=yy`. My pages were structured as follows:

```
www.website.net/infos.php?age=full&month=10&year=1972
www.website.net/infos.php?age=short&month=12&year=1972
www.website.net/diary.php?page=18&month=3&year=2016
www.website.net/diary.php?page=2&month=7&year=1994
www.website.net/web.php?lang=en&skin=elegant&month=2&year=1987
www.website.net/diary.php?page=3&month=2&year=1987
www.website.net/diary.php?page=18&month=7&year=1990
www.website.net/index.php?month=12&year=1947
```

As you can see by clicking on `Previous` and `Next` you would navigate between the months of a given year. I then realized that Google had first indexed all my pages with those parameters and then decided, since the pages didn't have many differences according to Google, to mark the pages with the parameters month and year as duplicates and to remove them from indexing. Realizing what had happened, I decided to remove the month and year parameters from my calendar so that they would no longer be clickable (the pages no longer produced the month and year parameters), but Google instead continued to try to index the pages with month and year parameters. Obviously the number of pages excluded is increased because Google has noticed that there was no difference between a page with `month=2` & `year=1974` and another page with `month=7` & `year=1997`. So I decided to serve a `404` error to Google when scanning pages with the parameters month and year.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} month= [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} year= [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/err/404\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/err/.*\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

It worked great! But I was wondering if it was better to remove the month and year parameters on the fly by allowing Google to index the pages without those parameters.

So I wrote a rule to remove the month and year parameters on the fly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?month=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?year=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

It works except in one case that is when for example there is the number `2` as a parameter. An example:

```
www.website.net/diary.php?page=2&month=2&year=1992
```

In this case my rule also deletes the `page=2` parameter and the url becomes:

```
www.website.net/diary.php
```

without any parameter. My question is therefore the following: how to eliminate the parameters month and year on the fly keeping all the other parameters intact in the url using .htaccess and mod rewrite.

Thanks.

Comment: I would really rather do this from within the PHP script(s) directly, than try to fix it with mod_rewrite.

Comment: You can use https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test what happens. Starting with the input URL `http://www.website.net/diary.php?page=2&month=12&year=1972`, it redirects to `http://www.website.net/diary.php?page=2&year=1972` first; and if you then feed in that URL for a second round, the result is `http://www.website.net/diary.php?page=2&%2`. If `%2` did not get replaced, it means the preceding RewriteCond did not capture a second match.

Comment: I see the bug! Thanks, exists a way to solve this?

Comment: Well you could write even more condition/rule combinations, that handle the different cases individually (is there something before what you want to remove or not, is there something after what you want to remove or not) … but again, I would really rather do this in PHP.

Comment: I already removed the get month and year variables a while ago and my integrated calendar no longer produces links to navigate between the months of a given year. The problem is that Google thinks those variables still exist and tries to index the pages with those parameters anyway. On the PHP side I've already solved the problem, now it's enough for me to just let Google understand it using .htaccess.

Comment: I did not mean _that_ part of the problem (generating the correct links in the first place), but the part you are currently trying to solve in .htaccess, with an already rather complex setup of conditions & rules - I’d do _that_ in PHP as well. Check if $_GET contains these parameters you don’t want, and if so, create the new correct URL without them, and issue a 301 redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I would like to do this using .htaccess because with this way it is easy to change idea because it is a matter of deleting a rule from this file, the way of PHP is good but by changing to the php files concerned, in case you want to change idea, you should change the php code for get it back to how it was before. The easiest and most painless thing is .htaccess, a rule of a few lines and go! Thanks!

Comment: `In this case my rule also deletes the page=2` - No it doesn't. Those 2 rules don't remove `page=` parameter. Make sure you test in a new browser and there is no other redirect rule impacting this URL.

Comment: However from SEO perspective it would be better to remove both unwanted parameters in one redirect instead of 2 `301` redirects.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. My rule doesn't work as expected and if you could suggest me the correct rule I'll appreciate very much.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I asked a specific question, but I solved my complicated situation in another way and editing my robots.txt file and adding the following rules:

```
#Stop Indexing Unwanted URL Parameters

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?age=

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*&age=

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?post=

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*&post=

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?month=

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*&month=

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?year=

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*&year=

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?p=

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*&p=
```

I can see that Google no more tried to indexing this parameters.

Thanks for every suggestion given. Thanks.